# The bike of Tom or the bike of Tom's - questions about possessives

Tags: possessives, double-possessives

I wonder which expression is correct in my examples. I know the better way to say them is "Tom's bike" and "Tom's home", but I am still curious about the form in the examples as it is quite common in cases where the name are just too long to use apostrophe.

Example 1:

> (1) I am going to ride the bike of Tom.
>
> (2) I am going to ride the bike of Tom's.

Example 2:

> (3) I am going to the home of Tom.
>
> (4) I am going to the home of Tom's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this poor man's humble opinion,

In Example 1: '**(1) I am going to ride the bike *of* Tom.**' is better as you are already indicating possessiveness through the use of '**of**'.

Similarly,

In Example 2: '**(3)  I am going to the home *of* Tom.**' is better as you are already indicating possessiveness through the use of '**of**'.

Hope this helped.

Comment: That is correct. We would never say 'the bike of Tom's'. 'I am going to ride _a_ bike of Tom's' would suggest that Tom owns several bikes and is lending one to you.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Your replies have helped me make gains in grammar.

Comment: This is an old answer now but I think it's worth registering my disagreement with it. *The bike of Tom* and *the home of Tom* are not idiomatic English - we would say *Tom's bike* or *Tom's home* (or more usually *Tom's house*). However we might say *of Tom's* in an expression such as *That new bike of Tom's looks expensive!*.